# sql query to join and concat values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

**sql server: 2012**

These are 3 tables.

First table is the user's (consultants) table
The second one is the prices table, each user from the first column has a price
The last table define in what area (city) the consultants offer services

```
Consultants      Prices           Area
uid | Name       uid | Price      uid | City
----|-----      -----|-------     ----|------
1   | Dave        1  |  5           1 | NY
2   | Adrian      2  |  7           1 | LA
3   | John        4  |  5           4 | NY
4   | Lee                           4 | NO
                                    4 | LA 
                                    4 | SF
```

I need to select from all the table something like this:

```
uid  |  Price   | City
-----|----------|-------
 1   |    5     | NY, LA
-----|----------|-------
 2   |    7     | 
-----|----------|-------
 4   |    5     | NY, NO, LA, SF
-----|----------|-------
```

How do I do this select? Any idea?

Comment: You can use `FOR XML PATH`. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server) for example.

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't specified Database, Assuming SQL Server 2008, You can Use [STUFF function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and [Group BY Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) to concanate multiple rows into Single Comma separated Values

```
Select C.uid, P.price, ISNULL(A.City,'') City
From Consultants C
     INNER JOIN Prices P ON C.uid = P.uid
     LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT  UID
                         ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(city AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
                         FROM Area
                         WHERE UID = t.UID
                         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                         .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') CITY
                  FROM Area t
                  GROUP BY UID ) A 
      ON C.uid = A.uid
```

[Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89c44/17)

Comment: what is your Database, Sql Server or My SQL

Comment: My satabase is SqlServer. Your solution works perfect! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

may be this way also you can do

```
declare @consultants table (uid int,name varchar(10))
insert into @consultants (uid,name)values (1,'dave'),(2,'adrian'),(3,'jon'),(4,'lee')
declare @Prices table (uid int,price int)
insert into @Prices(uid,price)values (1,5),(2,7),(4,5)

declare @Area table (uid int,city varchar(5))
insert into @Area(uid,city)values (1,'NY'),(1,'LA'),(4,'NY'),(4,'LA'),(4,'SF'),(4,'NO')

select t.uid,tt.price,ISNULL(STUFF((select  +', '+ city from @Area where uid = t.uid FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                         .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' '),'')CITY  from @consultants t INNER JOIN @Prices tt
ON t.uid = tt.uid
```